# FB Login - Authorization popup opens 2 times

Tags: javascript, authentication, facebook-javascript-sdk

if i am already connected to fb, bt not authorized to app it opens popup 2 times… i tried below code... there is no error in console....

```
   if (response.authResponse) {
       console.log("user is already logged in and connected");
       console.log("Fetching Info..... - already logged in");

       FB.api('/me', function(info) {
         login(response, info);
       });

       // button.onclick = function() {
       // FB.logout(function(response) {
       // logout(response);
       // });
       // };
   } else {
       console.log("user is not connected to your app or logged out");

       $('.login-with-fb-instant').click(function(e) {
         e.preventDefault();
         console.log("Fetching Info..... - logged out");
         $('.fb-loader').show();
         FB.login(function(response) {
           if (response.authResponse) {
             FB.api('/me', function(info) {
              login(response, info);
             });
           } else {
             console.log("user cancelled login or did not grant authorization");
             $('.fb-loader').hide();
           }
         }, {
             scope : 'email,user_birthday,status_update,publish_stream,user_about_me'
         });
      });
  }`enter code here`
```

Comment: It is due to your scope variable. First popup for basic profile andother is for extended permissions, it is normal behaviour

Comment: any code suggestions to correct it?@Hüseyin BABAL

Comment: What do you mean with popup? The popup belongs facebook authorization?

Comment: ya. thats facebook authorization

Comment: That is normal behaviour. First thing you need to do is decide which scope variable do you need. According to your scope variables, one or two popup will be open for the first time